# Bot can not take out [amount] of coins to give to someone from there wallet unless they have [amount] enough in there bank

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For my economy bot, i have wallet and bank for each member. Im currently making a give command. Say for example, I want to give someone 5 coins. The bot will take out 5 coins from MY wallet and put it in THEIR wallet. This works fine but there is one issue. If i want to give someone 5 coins and i HAVE enough in MY wallet but NOT in my bank, the bot says that I don't have enough money to do this. But if i do have enough in my bank that im trying to give, then it will work. But im not trying to take it out of my bank. Screenshots are below to demonstrate what im talking about.

[image]

You see here that i have 10 coins in my wallet so i can give this to someone. But since there is not 10 enough in my bank, i get this.

[image]

I should still be able to give 10 coins to this user because I have 10 coins in my wallet?
My question is, how can I still give a user 10 coins by taking it away from MY wallet and into THEIR wallet without having it to check my bank amount? Code is below, thx in advanced!

My **FUNCTIONS:**

```
async def get_bank_data():
    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        return users


async def update_bank(user, change=0, mode="wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

        bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"], users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]
        return bal


async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

        with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
            return True
```

My **CODE:**

```
@bot.command()
async def give(ctx, member : discord.Member, amount=None):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  await open_account(member)

  if amount == None:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Please enter the amount that you want to give to {member.name}!")
    return

  bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
  amount = int(amount)

  if amount < 1:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your withdraw amount needs to be larger than 0!")
    return
  if amount > bal[1]:
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You do not have enough money in your wallet to do this!")
    return

  await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount,"wallet")
  await update_bank(member,amount,"wallet")

  await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You just took out `{amount}` Ulti Coins from your wallet and gave it to {member.name}'s wallet!")
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far to overcome this "error"?

Comment: Does it always go from wallet to wallet? Or do you want it to go from bank to bank and wallet to wallet? How do you determine which one the coins go into.

Comment: @Asis wallet to wallet. i do not wank bank involved at all.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting but can you decide what you want? I spent hours on coding this for you and deleted my answer as you indeed want to have `bank` involved if there is not enough money in the `wallet`... This is simply just a waste of time as I mentioned multiple times we only have `bal[1]` and `mode="wallet"` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our [conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/232674), I am now submitting a response again.

So you want only `wallet` to be considered here and `bank` to be **completely** omitted. You then want to work with that later.

To work with the current `wallet` value we need a new function, like as if we would query the value from the JSON:

```py
user = ctx.author
users = await get_bank_data()
wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] # wallet only
```

Now we want only `wallet` to be looked at in all further steps, so we remove all `"bank"` statements and change them to `"wallet"`.

**With our new `wallet_amt` function we can now start different queries:**

```py
if amount > wallet_amt: # Amount entered too large for wallet?
    return await ctx.send("**You do not have enough money in your wallet.**")

if amount < wallet_amt: # If amount is true/smaller
    await update_bank(ctx.author, -1 * amount, "wallet")
    await update_bank(member, amount, "wallet")
    await ctx.send(f "**We took {amount} coins from your wallet.**")
    return
```

**So in a whole code, it would look like this:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def give(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, amount: int = None):
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]

    if member is None:
        return await ctx.send("**Please define a member.**")

    if amount is None:
        return await ctx.send("**Please enter an amount.**")

    await open_account(ctx.author)
    await open_account(member)

    if amount > wallet_amt:
        return await ctx.send("**You do not have enough money to do this.**")

    if amount < wallet_amt:
        await update_bank(ctx.author, -1 * amount, "wallet")
        await update_bank(member, amount, "wallet")

    if amount < 0:
        await ctx.send("**The amount must be positive.**")
        return

    await update_bank(ctx.author, -1 * amount, "wallet") # Needed
    await update_bank(member, amount, "wallet") # Needed

    await ctx.send(f "**You gave {amount} coins to {member}.**")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, a few things. I want it to go from someone's wallet to somebody elses wallet, not their bank. Also, if someone does not have enough money in their bank AND wallet, it still gives the person {amount} the person specifed. and not return that they dont have enough money.

Comment: Then just change `bank` to `wallet`, should not be that hard. The other error you may be able to fix yourself with a little thinking. I have provided here at least the beginning that you asked for.

Comment: Thanks lol i dont know why I asked this question, had a long day XD.

Comment: If you are not able to fix the error let me know and I will guide you further/edit my answer.

Comment: So actaully other people were testing it, if they dont have enough money in there bank, even though were giving from our wallet, it still says that they dont have enough in there wallet to give.

Comment: As requested in your post we now just look at `wallet` and ignore everything about `bank`, I made an edit to my previous answer.

Comment: I worked on it after we talked last night and I got it working by myself. Thanks

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer so we can see what you actually wanted?

Comment: Sure i can do that

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was that it was reading the member's wallet amount and not mine so if they did not have the {amount} that I was trying to give, it would not work.

```
@commands.command()
    async def give(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, amount=None):
      await open_account(ctx.author)
      await open_account(member)

      if amount is None:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Please enter the amount that you want to give!")
        return

      users = await get_bank_data()
      bal = users[str(ctx.author.id)]["wallet"] #PROBLEM HERE, changed user.id to ctx.author.id

      amount = int(amount)

      if amount < 1:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your amount needs to be larger than 0!")
        return
      elif amount > bal:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You do not have enough money in your wallet to do this!")
        return
      elif amount <= bal:
        await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount, "wallet")
        await update_bank(member, amount, "wallet")
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You just gave `{amount}` Ulti Coins to {member.name}!")
```

Comment: Just to check in with you: That is the exact same solution I provided just that I took some more steps to define `user` as `author.id` in the end but I can see what you were trying to do now, my code is just a bit "longer".